# Phone under 145mm

Tags: android, smartphones, apple

I want to replace my iPhone 7 Plus with smaller device. Unfortunately, it is quite hard to find a good phone. Could you please advise me?

Usage: calls, messaging, music, working with my photo gallery and taking some photos when I do not have my DSLR camera present.

I found these ones:

- Google Pixel 4a
- Samsung Galaxy S10e
- iPhone XS, 11 Pro, 12 Mini, SE 2020

https://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?nYearMin=2018&nHeightMax=145&nRamMin=2000&sOSes=2,3&sOSversions=2920,2910,2900,2810,3940,3930,3920,3910,3900,3800,3700

Surprisingly, no Huawei, Xiaomi in the list.

Unfortunately, Pixel is not officially present in Czech Republic and S10e is sold with Exynos only. 12 Mini is too expensive for my needs.

Comment: iPhone SE 2 looks like a solid option.